# How can i get unique count aggregation by field value with Spring Data?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm trying to do this:

[http://prntscr.com/mb3xqx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGNCt.png)

with Spring Data Elasticsearch, but i can't find a way to make Unique Count aggregation by field value.

```
SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
            .withIndices("logs-processing-*")
            .addAggregation(terms("procedure_code").field("procedure_code.keyword"))
            .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Cant test right now, but pretty sure you should try: .addAggregation(terms("procedure_code").field("keyword"))

Comment: My code works fine, it returns buckets with count of documents for each procedure code. But i want to count only unique documents. In my case uniqueness is determined by the field "prcd_id".

Comment: Ah ok, add a sub aggregation on "prcd_id"